# Autocomplete nested_form field in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, autocomplete, nested-forms

I started learning rails 3 recently. I'm thinking about the best way to implement an autocomplete feature.

I have 4 models in my rails application with the following structure.

```
class User
  has_many :friendships
  has_many :bills
end

class Friendship
  belongs_to :user
end

class Bill
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :bill_splits
end

class BillSplit
  belongs_to :bill
  has_on :friendship
end
```

The idea behind `Bill` and `BillSplit` models is once a user creates a bill, the bill will automatically split depending on the number of friends the shares the bill with.

I use nested attributes on bill_split so that I can use a single form to create both bill and bill_split entries. I would like to add an autocomplete field for `friend_name` (user's list of friends from `Friendship`), along with `friendship_id` and then save. I'm wondering what's the best way to do this.

One possible way to do this is to create a virtual attribute `friend_name` in `bill_split` that autocompletes the names and also fills the `friendship_id`. The other is to remove `friendship_id` and replace it with `friend_name`. Are there any other ways to make this happen?

Also, is it also possible to reference a field in another model and not just the model itself?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried it?  In general it sounds like you have a pretty good idea of how to do it.  [JQuery Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/), a little javascript, some hidden fields with IDs...

Comment: If you are no longer having an issue, please choose an below to accept, or submit your own with details. Also upvote any that have been helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that you want to implement autocompleting text fields with nested forms. First off, I do not see any nested associations in your models. If the main form is for a `bill`, then you should add the following to its model:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :bill_splits
```

While `bill_splits` could stand alone, adding the above line to the `Bill` model will help in the controller, where you implement `:bill_split_attributes` array of params. Then, in your form, you call a `fields_for :bill_splits`, and proceed with nested forms as normal.

Now, in regards to autocompletion... Whether you are still on Rails 3 or have upgraded to Rails 4, the [`rails-jquery-autocomplete`](https://github.com/bigtunacan/rails-jquery-autocomplete) gem is the official repository supporting both! It includes great documentation, as well as a sample app with nested form examples. The gem uses `jQuery UI autocomplete` library, and incorporates ActiveRecord entries into the dataset submitted.

Unfortunately, with the information you have provided, I am unable to help further with configuring the nested forms. As I said before, I do not know your table structure or your current code to better evaluate. Good news, the gem's maintainer is active and answering questions/issues!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to see this screencast http://railscasts.com/episodes/102-auto-complete-association

Also take a look **rails4-autocomplete** gem if you use rails4